# What is the difference between physical address space and installed physical memory?

Tags: memory, operating-system

I'm currently learning the basics of operating systems, and I got confused by this. I don't understand the difference, so if someone could clarify it, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Address space is a 5-gallon bucket.

Installed physical memory is the amount of water actually *in* the bucket.